# Deducing continuity of a random variable from CDF

Tags: continuity, random-variables

$$F_X\left(t\right)=\begin{cases}2^t&t<-1\\ \:\frac{1}{2}&-1\le t<1\\ \frac{t}{2}\:&1\le t<2\\ \:1&t\ge 2\end{cases}$$
How can I know if random variable $X$ is continuous\discrete\ none of them?
From talking to few friends from my study, they said this:
If the CDF is continuous , so $X$ is continuous.
or If the CDF is not star-case function ,then it $X$ is not discrete.
If the CDF is not continuous, then $X$ is not continuous

Which one of them( the sentences ) is correct, if any of them is correct? I am having trouble
proving this random variable $X$ is continuous.
and without any context for this CDF, but for CDF in general, how to deduce whether or not $X$ is Continuous\Discrete\None of them according to my CDF?

Comment: If $F$ is not continuous, $X$ is not continuous. If $F$ is differentiable with integrable derivative, $X$ is continuous. I'm not sure how much more you can say. $X$ is continuous iff. $\operatorname{Pr}(X\in A)=0$ for all Lebesgue-null sets $A$ but I'm not sure if that can be inferred from a continuous-but-not-differentiable cumulative distribution

Comment: If $F$ is absolutely continuous then we can argue $X$ is continuous

Comment: Hi, regarding Statement1: $F$ not continious $\rightarrow$ $X$ not continious, got it......................... $F$ is differentiable, so $X$ is continious? you wrote F, is that a mistake?........................... about the third statement, yea, that I know but it is hard using that information.

Comment: But if $F$ is continuous, what can I say about $X$?  because my CDF is actually continuous, but not differentiable

Comment: @FShrike There may be a conflict in terminology. Some authors call continuous the random variables with continuous cdf and absolutely continuous the random variables with a pdf.

Comment: and regarding the first statement, does it mean $X$ is discrete? or it is or discrete \ or not discrete and not continuous

Comment: To us it is absolutely continuous always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your particular $F$ is piecewise with each piece being a continuously differentiable thus absolutely continuous function, it follows $F$ is absolutely continuous; it follows, even though $F$ isn't differentiable everywhere, that the distribution/the random variable is continuous (admits a density function).

It's also pretty obvious that the piecewise derivatives of $F$ will serve as the pdf here: $$f_X:x\mapsto\begin{cases}\ln(2)\cdot 2^t&t<-1\\0&-1\le t<1\\\frac{1}{2}&1\le t<2\\0&t\ge2\end{cases}$$

Comment: So I can take it that if my function is piecewise differentiable \ or $F$ is continuous ( basically same thing, no?), so $X$ is continuous? is it a sentence I can take?..........Yea, I did also myself, the PDF, but how does the PDF help me here? I reached same result as you.

Comment: @LearningToCode piecewise differentiable with 'nice' derivatives implies $X$ is continuous. But it is not "basically the same thing": $F$ can be continuous even if $X$ is not. Certainly, $F$ can be continuous without being (piecewise) differentiable

Comment: Oh I get it.
And regarding the PDF, how does the PDF helps me regarding continuity \ discrete of random variable? if I may ask. ( although it just shows me that F is piecewise differentiable )

Comment: @LearningToCode A random variable is continuous iff. it has a pdf. If $F$ is continuous, the random variable is not discrete

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: @LearningToCode no problem

Comment: Hi, just one last thing.... You said if $F$ is continuous, so the random variable is not discrete..... What does it mean? it is not continuous and not discrete?

Comment: @LearningToCode I don't know where "not continuous" came from. Because a discrete random variable has a 'staircase' function for $F$, we know $F$ wouldn't be continuous. So if $F$ **is** continuous, then the random variable is **not** discrete. That's all

Comment: Oh Got it, thanks!